# mysql stored procedure with the if condition gives errors

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select, stored-procedures

I have the following code of creating a stored procedure in `mysql`.

```
mysql>delimiter |
mysql>create procedure GetCustomerLevel()
     -> if(select count(name) from s_marks)<4
     ->  then
     ->   begin
     ->    select 'inside the if statement' as'';
     ->    select 'there are lassee than 4 students' as '';
     ->   end
     ->  else
     ->     select 'there are more than 4 stu' as '';
     ->  end if|
```

But it gives me this error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'else
>   select 'there are more than 4 stu' as '';
>   end if' at line 15

what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Mysql doesn't allow begin /end in the if else statement.That works only for sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working as below

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetCustomerLevel`()
BEGIN
         if(select count(name) from s_marks)<4
      then

        select 'inside the if statement' as'';
        select 'there are lassee than 4 students' as '';

      else
         select 'there are more than 4 stu' as '';
      end if;
END
```